# Как разбить на токены выражение "5/-4" и "5*-4" Python

Tags: python

У меня есть функция - токенизатор, которая преобразовывает в токены математическое выражение.

Токенизатор:

```
def tokenization(expr):
    tokens = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+|[()+\-*/]', expr)
    return tokens
```

Если в эту функцию загрузить строку "5/-4" или "5*-4", то в ответ мы получим:

**Input**: 5/-4

**Output**: ["5", "/", "-", "4"]

**Ожидаемый результат:** ["5", "/", "-4"]

Аналогично с умножением:

**Input**: 5*-4

**Output**: ["5", "*", "-", "4"]

**Ожидаемый результат:** ["5", "*", "-4"]

Как сделать так, чтобы токенизатор выдавал лист, который я описал в ожидаемом результате?

Comment: Это  не функциональность токенизатора. Если вы считаете что `-` должен быть присоединён к литералу за ним, это нужно делать позже, так как зависит от контекста. Сравните `1-1` и `1+-1`. В первом случае `-` - отдельная операция, во втором случае - часть литерала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я решил полностью отказаться от регулярных выражений и решил задачу с помощью алгоритма сортировочных станций. Мой код может быть далеко не идеальным и возможно считает не правильно, а в некоторых случаях может ломаться, но в моем проекте - калькуляторе я попробовал достаточно большое количество различных выражений со скобками, отрицательными числами и числами с плавающей точкой, различные комбинации и код ни разу не сломался.

Вот сам код токенизации выражения:

```
def tokenization(expression):
    """Разбивка мат. выражения на токены"""

    tokens = []
    i = 0 # Индекс элемента в выражении
    temp_token = "" # Если встречается 2 мат. оператора подряд ( наприм. 1*-1), то хранит последний

    if expression[0] in '/*-+':
        expression = "0" + expression

    while i < len(expression):
        # Если символ - цифра или точка, то добавляем его в токен и в цикле перебираем следующие символы
        if expression[i].isdigit() or expression[i] == '.':
            num_token = []

            # Если в temp_token больше 2 мат. операторов - Ошибка
            if len(temp_token) > 1:
                raise ValueError("Error: Ошибка в выражении!")

            # Если в temp_token есть оператор, то прибавить его к началу будущего числа
            elif temp_token:
                num_token.append(temp_token)
                temp_token = ""

            # Перебираем и добавляем следующие символы в токен до первого не-числа и не-точки.
            while i < len(expression) and (expression[i].isdigit() or expression[i] == '.'):
                num_token.append(expression[i])
                i += 1
            tokens.append("".join(num_token))

         # Если символ - оператор, то смотрим, какие символы идут после него
        elif expression[i] in '/*-+':
            op_token = []
            while i < len(expression) and expression[i] in "/*-+":
                if expression[i - 1] == '(':
                    tokens.append('0')
                op_token.append(expression[i])
                i += 1

            if len(op_token) > 1:
                temp_token = "".join(op_token[1:])
                op_token = op_token[0]
            tokens.append("".join(op_token))

        # Если символ - скобка, то добавляем его как отдельный токен
        elif expression[i] in '()':
            while i < len(expression) and expression[i] in "()":
                tokens.append(expression[i])
                i += 1

        # Иначе пропускаем символ
        else:
            i += 1
    return tokens
```

Comment: Во время эксплуатации нашелся баг. Допустим, выражение: `2*-(1+2)`. После бинарного `*` стоит унарный `-`, который, к сожалению, не работает и данное выражение парсится как `['2', '*', '(', '-1', '+', '2', ')']` и в ответе получается число 2.

Answer (score 1):

Я немного изменил функцию. Попробуй такой вариант:

```
def tokenization(expr):
    tokens = re.findall(r'[()\*/]|-?\d+\.?\d*|\d+|[()\-*/]', expr)
    return tokens
```

Пример 1:

```
tokenization("5/-4")
>>['5', '/', '-4']
```

Пример 2:

```
tokenization("5*-4")
>>['5', '*', '-4']
```

Comment: Как будет разобрано `1-1`?

Comment: Как `['1', '-1']`. Это хороший кейс, возможно выражение следует улучшить

Comment: С помощью регулярных выражений как то можно посмотреть, что находится спереди числа, на котором мы остановились? Допустим, выражение 10/-5. Мы находим 10, копируем и заносим в новый лист. Следом идёт деление, смотрим, что находится перед делением-число, значит заносим в лист знак деления. Следом идёт минус, смотрим-спереди деление, значит это относится к элементу после, смотрим туда - а там число. Я очень плох в регулярках, а также я не знаю, будет ли работать этот способ в других мат. Выражениях, возможно мой способ очень узко направлен. Но как его можно попытаться реализовать?

Comment: Ваше выражение всегда состоит из числа, знака и второго числа? Или предусматривается, что функция будет принимать выражения любой длины?

Comment: Пользователь сам вводит выражение. Оно может быть любой последовательности и любого размера. Могут использоваться как положительные числа, так и отрицательные, как целые, так и дробные, также могут использоваться скобки